# spring mvc - error null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I try to insert data to database but get internal server error `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I create my own spring MVC maybe its different from other

I think the error occurs because the model does not do get data from the body so that when calling the save method occurs a null pointer exception error

here the code

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RestController
public class SellerController {

@Autowired
SellerService service;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "sellers/register",
            consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponsePost postSellerRegister(@RequestBody SellerPost model){

    ResponsePost response = new ResponsePost();
    model.getSlrNim();
    model.getStdId();
    model.getSlrName();
    model.getSlrPass();
    model.getSlrEmail();
    model.getSlrContact();
    model.getSlrGender();
    try{
            service.connectToDatabase();
            Result<Integer> result = service.save(model);
            response.setStatus(result.getStatus());
            response.setId(result.getModel());
            service.closeConnection();
    }catch(SQLException e) {
            response.setStatus(StateCons.SQL_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
@Service
public class SellerService extends BaseService implements BaseDao<SellerPost, SellerGet, SellerGet> {

public SellerService(){

}

@Override
public Result<Integer> save(SellerPost model){

    Result<Integer> result = new Result();
    if(getDatabase().getResult() == StateCons.SUCCESS){
            try{
                           String sql = "INSERT INTO seller (slr_nim, slr_name, std_id, slr_gender, slr_email, slr_contact, slr_pass) VALUES ('"+ model.getSlrNim() +"', '"+ model.getSlrName() + "', '"+ model.getStdId() +"', "+ model.getSlrGender() +", '"+ model.getSlrEmail() +"', '" + model.getSlrContact() +"', '"+ model.getSlrPass() +"')";
                            setResultSet(getDatabase().executeQuery(sql));
                            if(getResultSet().next()) {
                                    result.setModel(new Integer(getResultSet().getInt("slr_nim")));
                                    result.setStatus(StateCons.SUCCESS);
                            }else{
                                    result.setStatus(StateCons.FAILED);
                            }
                    getResultSet().close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                    result.setStatus(StateCons.NO_RECORD);
            }
    }else{
            result.setStatus(StateCons.FAILED);
    }
    return result;
 }
}
```

**DAO**

```
package id.ceban.dao;

import java.util.List;
import id.ceban.model.Result;

public interface BaseDao<P, G, GD> {

public Result<Integer> save(P model);

public Result<Boolean> delete(int modelId);

public Result<Boolean> update(P model, int modelId);

public Result<GD> get(int modelId);

public Result<List<G> > getList(String search_query, String field, String sort, int page, int limit);

public Result<Integer> count(int modelId);

}
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should add the error message.

Comment: @ChristianFrommeyer, even if he had been showing the errors, I'm pretty sure this question would end up asking the others to debug his codes, apparently he didn't show some effort from his side.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you shouldn't get a new instance of `SellerService`, should use `@Autowired`. You can try to replace this:

```
SellerService service = new SellerService();
```

For this:

```
@Autowired
SellerService service;
```

And the `SellerService` class should has `@Service` annotation before of the class definition:

```
@Service
public class SellerService extends BaseService implements BaseDao<SellerPost, SellerGet, SellerGet> {
//...
}
```

Comment: could you post the new stack trace?

Comment: i've changed it. the error is in the same line. the error is result.getModel() is null